# accesskey internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, access-keys

I have a weird problem, I can not mek work the accesskey on any version of Internet Explorer.

My code :

```
<a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/accessibilite" accesskey="0"></a>
```

The accesskey work on chrome and firefox but not in intenet explorer, if anybo have a solution, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To access the shortcut key in IE, you should press Alt + accesskey.

Prevent using the existing shortcut keys in the IE's menu and also, try to use other characters like "s"

In my case, I've tested it with IE11 and it works for character "s" but not "0" for some reason

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" accesskey="s">StackOverflow</a>
```